# How to retrieve Job Applications from Facebook Page using graph API

Tags: facebook

I wanted to retrieve job applications from Facebook page using graph API. In the graph explorer i have applied my page Id in node. where we can see several fields like post, conversations, likes... Now if a person clicked "Apply now" button on facebook page. Facebook will capture the vital information to prepare resume. Now i wanted to pull those information against the job post. How is it possible using graph api https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs ?

Comment: Above doesn't help. Can you please give some samples

Answer (score 0):

I believe that facebook requires you to set up a recruiting manager to access the jobs feed via that user instead of accessing the job information via the graph api for a page.  This ensures that the business that owns the page has one person assigned to handling the job interactions and that the application information is being kept secure.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/jobs-xml/how-to/